# Android Progressbar showing/hiding while loading data

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I need help on this: Showing/hiding a progressbar while retrieving data from external source.

I've got this progressbar declared in the activity layout resource file:

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

In the onCreate activity method it is made invisible:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The before retrieving data from de server I show it -that is what I intent to do:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Then when the data is retrieved, I intent to hide it again with:

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But of course, not working as I pretend.
What is wrong with the code or this approach to show a simple progressbar while the app is contacting the server for data?

Comment: your current code is ok. please share your code which include show progressbar + retrieve data + hide progressbar

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching data from the server you have to just follow the below simple steps:-

**step 1** : make the visibility of the progress bar as gone/invisible.

**step 2** : show the progress bar just before making a call to the server.

**step 3** : on the on response success callback just make the progress bar
invisible again.

just follow the same steps whether using Retrofit or(volley / async task )

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, that is pretty much what I'm doing. I make it visible just before call.enqueue retrofit call and later in the callback make it invisible again. I've tried using invisible/gone but is the same. One thing if I don't make it invisible in the onCreate Activity method, the spinning is running and that's what confuse me. Any clue of what can be going on...?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is correct - the 'issue' you're having is there is no progress so it looks like your code isn't working.

You have to set the progress too. Generally when downloading a file, or some data, or loading a page we have a progress that is returned in the callback. If you don't have something like that you could just increment your progress bar each second or someting (or just use a spinning/infinite progress bar instead).

This is how you would do it though:

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using it as a spinning/infinite progress bar and I've said in the onCreate Activity method I make it invisible, before the retrofit call make it visible and then in the callback make it invisible again. One more thing, if I don't make invisible in the onCreate, the spinning is running.

Answer (score 0):

The code and logic were right what I've missed was to set the property "indeterminate=true" for the progressbar:

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:indeterminate="true"/>
```